# Postgres Raise all Exception in the end of file execution

Tags: sql, postgresql, exception, plpgsql

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  -- Check to make sure that event starts after users created
  IF EXISTS (
    SELECT users.id
    FROM event
    INNER JOIN users ON event.user_id::INT = users.id
    WHERE event.start > users.created
  )
  THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'SUCCESSFUL %', now();
  ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'ERROR on % - All Event start timestamps must be created after users are created',now();
  END IF;

END $$;
```

This exception is to check for timestamps and works well. But I want to add a similar condition and at-least 3 more exception conditions. I want to now return the exceptions at the end. I do-not want process to stop if first check fails. I want all the failed tests to be raised all at once in the end. How do I do that ? I read about stacked diagnostics bu dontt know if its the right approach or should I just use IF-else if ?

Answer (score 1):

It is in the nature of an exception to interrupt processing, so you cannot simply use exceptions for that.

You could collect all exceptions in a (temporary?) table and communicate them to the client in the end, or concatenate them to a single large exception.

You could also emit the individual messages as `NOTICE` and throw an exception at the end.